# Custom Google map style

Tags: google-maps

I don't know very much about javascript and API. I was wondering though if there's an easy way to customize a google map like in this example. How did they do it?

http://pooliestudios.com/kontakt/

Also where can I find a database of premade styles? Like http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor (if such thing exist for Google maps)

**edit**: Just found this site, check out http://snazzymaps.com/ for some cool premade styles.

Comment: Now in 2018, snazzymaps has a lot of pre-made styles. You can find how to create a custom style by yourself and apply that in map API from here - https://youtu.be/yzMddgWtoJA